# Copying SQLite Database from bundle to documents for writing?

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

So I am trying to copy my database which is currently in the main bundle to the documents so I can write to it instead of just being able to read from it. Right now I have as follows and it just can't find the database, the NSLog("Found database"); does not show up, so therefore the copying isn't working. I've been working on this for a while however I just can't figure it out.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED VERSION**

```
   - (IBAction)update:(id)sender {
    @try {
    /*
    NSString *docsPath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StayhealthyExercises-1.sqlite"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
     */

    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* dbPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StayhealthyExercises-1.sqlite"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if (!fileExists) {
        NSLog(@"Didn't find database");
        // get the source path to copy from
       // NSString *dbSourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"StayhealthyExercises-1" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        NSString *dbSourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath  ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StayhealthyExercises-1.sqlite"];
        // copy db to documents
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dbSourcePath toPath:dbPath error:nil];
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    const char *sql = "UPDATE stretchingexercises SET isFavorite = 'true' WHERE ID = '1'";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{
        if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"Success");
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

}
```

**OLD VERSION**

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
return basePath;
}

- (IBAction)update:(id)sender {
@try {
    NSString *docsPath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StayhealthyExercises-1.sqlite"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if (!fileExists) {
        NSLog(@"Found Database");
        // get the source path to copy from
        NSString *dbSourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath  ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StayhealthyExercises-1.sqlite"];
        // copy db to documents
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dbSourcePath toPath:dbPath error:nil];
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    const char *sql = "UPDATE stretchingexercises SET isFavorite = 'true' WHERE ID = '1'";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{
        if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"Success");
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

}
```

Comment: That's because your path is not pointing to [NSBundle mainBundle] but to NSDocumentDirectory or whatever.

Comment: did you check the file at document folder path?

Comment: @retro yes its not there

Comment: and your code is not going into if block? strange!

Comment: What does dbPath point to, [NSBundle mainBundle] or NSDocumentDirectory, in your code?  Take a good look at the lines right before if (!fileExists) { .

Comment: @RobertSaunders try resetting the simulator and then run the app for the first time to see if the db is copied the first time and also please check what the value of fileExists

Comment: If you ever ran your app before you had this "check before I try to open" logic refined, you might have inadvertently created a blank database (when `sqlite3_open` does not find a database it will create a blank one!). So, if you've been playing around with this for a while, you may want to reset your simulator (or manually remove the app from your simulator; either way, you'll guarantee to delete any blank databases that may have accidentally been created while you were playing around with this), and then try again.

Comment: NSLog both paths and make sure they're correct by "walking" to the same location in `Finder`.  And use `pathForResource:ofType:` to find the file in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code for getting dbPath in the first if block in **- (IBAction)update:(id)sender** with the code below:

```
 NSString *dbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"StayhealthyExercises-1" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

Comment: @retro ok so now I have updated my answer with the code i have now, but now I get the NSLog("Success"), but the query is not working, and I know the query should work. I have tried deleting the app so I would get rid of the blank databases if there was one, any suggestions?

Comment: @RobertSaunders - So when the query it fails, what does sqlite_errmsg report?

Comment: @RobertSaunders Check if the table exists in the database after copying database to the document directory. Sometimes what happens is you end up creating a database in the document directory instead of copying it. So the new database created in the document directory won't have the tables. The query might also fail because there was no such table in the database in document directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to check the file existence

```
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CopyFileNameFromMainBundle.db"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];
```

This should return `NO`

Comment: ok so now I have updated my answer with the code i have now, but now I get the NSLog("Success"), but the query is not working, and I know the query should work. I have tried deleting the app so I would get rid of the blank databases if there was one, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a problem with having the wrong log? Seems to me it should be like this:

```
....
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
if (!fileExists) {
    NSLog(@"Didn't Find Database in Documents Directory!");
    ...
} else {
    NSLog(@"Found Database in Documents Directory.");
}
...
```